# Does nGQL allow you to reference the VID of two tags in a query ? (rather the VID of one and the property of the other?

Tags: nebula-graph

I use the following two queries in nGQL to create instances of two tags:

```
INSERT VERTEX Topic (topicId, first_proposed, approval_status,
followers, tagged_tally) VALUES 9999:("Sample topic id", TIMESTAMP(),
"Pending", 10, 20);

INSERT VERTEX Post(text_added, last_updated, author, postId,
creation_date, shared_total, flagged_total, views, total_likes,
is_a_repost, post_format) VALUES 4444: ("Sample text", timestamp(),
"John Doe", 1234, TIMESTAMP(), 0, 0, 0, 0, false, "some format");
```

I use the following edge multiple times between the topic instance with VID 9999 and the Post with VID 4444, in which I change the timestamp value, and to do so I repeat the following INSERT EDGE statement:

```
INSERT EDGE is_tagged (when_tagged) VALUES 4444 -> 9999:(timestamp('2023-06-11T02:18:43'));
```

I now wish to count the total number of these edge occurrences. The closest I have managed is the following:

```
GO FROM 4444 OVER is_tagged WHERE $$.Topic.topicId == "Sample topic id" YIELD edge AS e | GROUP BY $-.e YIELD COUNT(*) AS number;
```

However I wish to reference 9999 and not have to replace the VID for Topic with the property value of Topic_id. How can I do this ? Ideally I want something akin to this:

```
GO FROM 4444 OVER is_tagged
WHERE VERTEX_ID($$.Topic) == "destination_topic_vid"
```

or this:

```
GO FROM 4444 OVER is_tagged
WHERE destination(is_tagged)._dst == 9999
YIELD edge AS e | GROUP BY $-.e YIELD COUNT(*) AS number;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we know exactly the source and dest VID of the given edge, we could do `FETCH` to get the edges between the two, your intuition of specifying VID not prop value is correct.

```
FETCH PROP ON serve "player100" -> "team204" YIELD src(edge) | YIELD count(*)
```

One more thing, `INSERT EDGE is_tagged (when_tagged) VALUES 4444 -> 9999:(timestamp('2023-06-11T02:18:43'));`  multiple times will not insert multiple instances of `is_tagged` edges, instead, it updates one edge's prop:when_tagged a couple of times after the first INSERT.

One instance of edge in NebulaGraph is (src_id, dst_id, type, rank), where by default, rank is 0 when it's omitted, to enable multiple instances of a given edge per pair of (src, dst), we could put timestamp as RANK field.

Like:

```
INSERT EDGE is_tagged (when_tagged) VALUES 4444 -> 9999@1686449923:(timestamp('2023-06-11T02:18:43'));
INSERT EDGE is_tagged (when_tagged) VALUES 4444 -> 9999@1686449983:(timestamp('2023-06-11T02:19:43'));
```

Hope it helps, and welcome to the NebulaGraph community!

BR//Wey

---

update, regarding the approach to do with `GO`, it's underlying do "expand" from start node to all its edges, then filter, thus technically it's a bit of more expensive :).

See:

```
-----+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | name      | dependencies | profiling data                | operator info                                                                                   |
-----+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  4 | Aggregate | 3            | {                             | outputVar: {                                                                                    |
|    |           |              |   "execTime": "40(us)",       |   "colNames": [                                                                                 |
|    |           |              |   "rows": 1,                  |     "count(*)"                                                                                  |
|    |           |              |   "totalTime": "44(us)",      |   ],                                                                                            |
|    |           |              |   "version": 0                |   "type": "DATASET",                                                                            |
|    |           |              | }                             |   "name": "__Aggregate_4"                                                                       |
|    |           |              |                               | }                                                                                               |
|    |           |              |                               | inputVar: __Project_3                                                                           |
|    |           |              |                               | groupKeys: []                                                                                   |
|    |           |              |                               | groupItems: [                                                                                   |
|    |           |              |                               |   {                                                                                             |
|    |           |              |                               |     "expr": "count(*)"                                                                          |
|    |           |              |                               |   }                                                                                             |
|    |           |              |                               | ]                                                                                               |
-----+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 | Project   | 2            | {                             | outputVar: {                                                                                    |
|    |           |              |   "execTime": "97(us)",       |   "colNames": [                                                                                 |
|    |           |              |   "rows": 1,                  |     "src(EDGE)"                                                                                 |
|    |           |              |   "totalTime": "110(us)",     |   ],                                                                                            |
|    |           |              |   "version": 0                |   "type": "DATASET",                                                                            |
|    |           |              | }                             |   "name": "__Project_3"                                                                         |
|    |           |              |                               | }                                                                                               |
|    |           |              |                               | inputVar: __Filter_2                                                                            |
|    |           |              |                               | columns: [                                                                                      |
|    |           |              |                               |   "src(EDGE)"                                                                                   |
|    |           |              |                               | ]                                                                                               |
-----+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 | Filter    | 1            | {                             | outputVar: {                                                                                    |
|    |           |              |   "execTime": "80(us)",       |   "colNames": [],                                                                               |
|    |           |              |   "rows": 1,                  |   "type": "DATASET",                                                                            |
|    |           |              |   "totalTime": "94(us)",      |   "name": "__Filter_2"                                                                          |
|    |           |              |   "version": 0                | }                                                                                               |
|    |           |              | }                             | inputVar: __GetEdges_1                                                                          |
|    |           |              |                               | condition: ((__EMPTY__!=serve._src) AND ((__EMPTY__!=serve._dst) AND (__EMPTY__!=serve._rank))) |
|    |           |              |                               | isStable: false                                                                                 |
-----+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | GetEdges  | 0            | {                             | outputVar: {                                                                                    |
|    |           |              |   "execTime": "840(us)",      |   "colNames": [],                                                                               |
|    |           |              |   "resp[0]": {                |   "type": "DATASET",                                                                            |
|    |           |              |     "exec": "2364(us)",       |   "name": "__GetEdges_1"                                                                        |
|    |           |              |     "host": "storaged2:9779", | }                                                                                               |
|    |           |              |     "total": "7274(us)"       | inputVar: __VAR_0                                                                               |
|    |           |              |   },                          | space: 11                                                                                       |
|    |           |              |   "rows": 1,                  | dedup: false                                                                                    |
|    |           |              |   "totalTime": "8126(us)",    | limit: 9223372036854775807                                                                      |
|    |           |              |   "total_rpc": "7652(us)",    | filter:                                                                                         |
|    |           |              |   "version": 0                | orderBy: []                                                                                     |
|    |           |              | }                             | src: COLUMN[0]                                                                                  |
|    |           |              |                               | type: "14"                                                                                      |
|    |           |              |                               | ranking: COLUMN[1]                                                                              |
|    |           |              |                               | dst: COLUMN[2]                                                                                  |
|    |           |              |                               | props: [                                                                                        |
|    |           |              |                               |   {                                                                                             |
|    |           |              |                               |     "props": [                                                                                  |
|    |           |              |                               |       "_dst",                                                                                   |
|    |           |              |                               |       "_rank",                                                                                  |
|    |           |              |                               |       "_src",                                                                                   |
|    |           |              |                               |       "_type",                                                                                  |
|    |           |              |                               |       "end_year",                                                                               |
|    |           |              |                               |       "start_year"                                                                              |
|    |           |              |                               |     ],                                                                                          |
|    |           |              |                               |     "type": 14                                                                                  |
|    |           |              |                               |   }                                                                                             |
|    |           |              |                               | ]                                                                                               |
|    |           |              |                               | exprs:                                                                                          |
-----+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | Start     |              | {                             | outputVar: {                                                                                    |
|    |           |              |   "execTime": "0(us)",        |   "colNames": [],                                                                               |
|    |           |              |   "rows": 0,                  |   "type": "DATASET",                                                                            |
|    |           |              |   "totalTime": "189(us)",     |   "name": "__Start_0"                                                                           |
|    |           |              |   "version": 0                | }                                                                                               |
|    |           |              | }                             |                                                                                                 |
-----+-----------+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thu, 29 Jun 2023 19:59:19 CST

(root@nebula) [basketballplayer]> PROFILE GO FROM "player100" OVER serve WHERE dst(edge) == "team204" YIELD edge AS e | YIELD COUNT(*) AS number;
+--------+
| number |
+--------+
| 1      |
+--------+
Got 1 rows (time spent 29.928ms/41.691958ms)

Execution Plan (optimize time 1842 us)

-----+-----------+--------------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------
| id | name      | dependencies | profiling data                        | operator info                     |
-----+-----------+--------------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------
|  6 | Aggregate | 5            | {                                     | outputVar: {                      |
|    |           |              |   "execTime": "44(us)",               |   "colNames": [                   |
|    |           |              |   "rows": 1,                          |     "number"                      |
|    |           |              |   "totalTime": "47(us)",              |   ],                              |
|    |           |              |   "version": 0                        |   "type": "DATASET",              |
|    |           |              | }                                     |   "name": "__Aggregate_6"         |
|    |           |              |                                       | }                                 |
|    |           |              |                                       | inputVar: __Project_5             |
|    |           |              |                                       | groupKeys: []                     |
|    |           |              |                                       | groupItems: [                     |
|    |           |              |                                       |   {                               |
|    |           |              |                                       |     "expr": "COUNT(*)"            |
|    |           |              |                                       |   }                               |
|    |           |              |                                       | ]                                 |
-----+-----------+--------------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------
|  5 | Project   | 4            | {                                     | outputVar: {                      |
|    |           |              |   "execTime": "37(us)",               |   "colNames": [                   |
|    |           |              |   "rows": 1,                          |     "e"                           |
|    |           |              |   "totalTime": "52(us)",              |   ],                              |
|    |           |              |   "version": 0                        |   "type": "DATASET",              |
|    |           |              | }                                     |   "name": "__Project_5"           |
|    |           |              |                                       | }                                 |
|    |           |              |                                       | inputVar: __Filter_4              |
|    |           |              |                                       | columns: [                        |
|    |           |              |                                       |   "EDGE AS e"                     |
|    |           |              |                                       | ]                                 |
-----+-----------+--------------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------
|  4 | Filter    | 3            | {                                     | outputVar: {                      |
|    |           |              |   "execTime": "31(us)",               |   "colNames": [                   |
|    |           |              |   "rows": 1,                          |     "EDGE"                        |
|    |           |              |   "totalTime": "41(us)",              |   ],                              |
|    |           |              |   "version": 0                        |   "type": "DATASET",              |
|    |           |              | }                                     |   "name": "__Filter_4"            |
|    |           |              |                                       | }                                 |
|    |           |              |                                       | inputVar: __ExpandAll_3           |
|    |           |              |                                       | condition: (dst(EDGE)=="team204") |
|    |           |              |                                       | isStable: false                   |
-----+-----------+--------------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------
|  3 | ExpandAll | 2            | {                                     | outputVar: {                      |
|    |           |              |   "execTime": "404(us)",              |   "colNames": [                   |
|    |           |              |   "graphExpandAllTime+2": "319(us)",  |     "EDGE"                        |
|    |           |              |   "resp[0]": {                        |   ],                              |
|    |           |              |     "exec": "7838(us)",               |   "type": "DATASET",              |
|    |           |              |     "host": "storaged2:9779",         |   "name": "__ExpandAll_3"         |
|    |           |              |     "storage_detail": {               | }                                 |
|    |           |              |       "GetNeighborsNode": "3837(us)", | inputVar: __Expand_2              |
|    |           |              |       "HashJoinNode": "3804(us)",     | space: 11                         |
|    |           |              |       "RelNode": "3838(us)",          | dedup: false                      |
|    |           |              |       "SingleEdgeNode": "3801(us)"    | limit: -1                         |
|    |           |              |     },                                | filter:                           |
|    |           |              |     "total": "15741(us)"              | orderBy: []                       |
|    |           |              |   },                                  | sample: false                     |
|    |           |              |   "rows": 1,                          | joinInput: false                  |
|    |           |              |   "totalTime": "18340(us)",           | maxSteps: 1                       |
|    |           |              |   "version": 0                        | edgeProps: [                      |
|    |           |              | }                                     |   {                               |
|    |           |              |                                       |     "props": [                    |
|    |           |              |                                       |       "_dst",                     |
|    |           |              |                                       |       "_rank",                    |
|    |           |              |                                       |       "_src",                     |
|    |           |              |                                       |       "_type",                    |
|    |           |              |                                       |       "end_year",                 |
|    |           |              |                                       |       "start_year"                |
|    |           |              |                                       |     ],                            |
|    |           |              |                                       |     "type": 14                    |
|    |           |              |                                       |   }                               |
|    |           |              |                                       | ]                                 |
|    |           |              |                                       | stepLimits: []                    |
|    |           |              |                                       | minSteps: 1                       |
|    |           |              |                                       | vertexProps:                      |
|    |           |              |                                       | vertexColumns: []                 |
|    |           |              |                                       | edgeColumns: [                    |
|    |           |              |                                       |   "EDGE AS EDGE"                  |
|    |           |              |                                       | ]                                 |
-----+-----------+--------------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------
|  2 | Expand    | 1            | {                                     | outputVar: {                      |
|    |           |              |   "execTime": "279(us)",              |   "colNames": [                   |
|    |           |              |   "rows": 1,                          |     "_expand_vid"                 |
|    |           |              |   "totalTime": "1274(us)",            |   ],                              |
|    |           |              |   "version": 0                        |   "type": "DATASET",              |
|    |           |              | }                                     |   "name": "__Expand_2"            |
|    |           |              |                                       | }                                 |
|    |           |              |                                       | inputVar: __VAR_0                 |
|    |           |              |                                       | space: 11                         |
|    |           |              |                                       | dedup: false                      |
|    |           |              |                                       | limit:                            |
|    |           |              |                                       | filter:                           |
|    |           |              |                                       | orderBy: []                       |
|    |           |              |                                       | sample: false                     |
|    |           |              |                                       | joinInput: false                  |
|    |           |              |                                       | maxSteps: 0                       |
|    |           |              |                                       | edgeProps: [                      |
|    |           |              |                                       |   {                               |
|    |           |              |                                       |     "props": [                    |
|    |           |              |                                       |       "_dst"                      |
|    |           |              |                                       |     ],                            |
|    |           |              |                                       |     "type": 14                    |
|    |           |              |                                       |   }                               |
|    |           |              |                                       | ]                                 |
|    |           |              |                                       | stepLimits: []                    |
-----+-----------+--------------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------
|  1 | Start     |              | {                                     | outputVar: {                      |
|    |           |              |   "execTime": "6(us)",                |   "colNames": [],                 |
|    |           |              |   "rows": 0,                          |   "type": "DATASET",              |
|    |           |              |   "totalTime": "407(us)",             |   "name": "__Start_1"             |
|    |           |              |   "version": 0                        | }                                 |
|    |           |              | }                                     |                                   |
-----+-----------+--------------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------
```

Comment: Its a pleasure to make your acquaintance Wey Gu,

The following gives the result 4444:   

FETCH PROP ON is_tagged 4444 -> 9999 YIELD src(edge)

I am not sure how to make the COUNT work with this also as | COUNT(*) gives the error: -1004:SyntaxError: syntax error near `COUNT'

Comment: Sorry, I missed one YIELD after the pipeline. it should be 
```
FETCH PROP ON serve "player100" -> "team204" YIELD src(edge) | YIELD count(*)
```
instead.

Comment: I added the profile between GO and FETCH here, we could see FETCH calls `GetEdges` here, and in theory it's a bit faster, but in most cases that will do the job perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

A colleague got it working with the following:

```
GO FROM 4444 OVER is_tagged WHERE dst(edge) == 9999  YIELD edge AS e | YIELD COUNT(*) AS number;
```

Comment:  Yes, this will do, but slightly more expensive when 4444 comes with a lot of edges(not to 9999)